# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Different's [4th moderator election](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: grgarside] [image: Monomeeth] [image: Glorfindel]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5636392960917504/0).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who voted making this the highest turnout for any Ask Different election! Congratulations to the new moderators and I look forward to continue working with you all over the coming years.

Comment: Thank you all for your confidence! I'm happy to be part of the team and I'm looking forward to moderate the site together with you *and* all the non-♦ users. A special thought goes out to Jackson, who made the election possible, and I'm sure he will continue to be a valuable member of this community.

Comment: Awesome, guys! Thanks for volunteering and welcome aboard!

Comment: Congratulations to everyone who nominated and/or voted. Your involvement and engagement is what helps make this site what it is! :) Congratulations also to grgarside and Glorfindel for their election. As for me personally, this is an honour and a privilege and I promise to give it my best, to engage all users, and to learn from whatever mistakes I make along the way. Let's work together to make Ask Different even better than what it already is! :)

Comment: Thanks for volunteering your time and good luck to you all! :)

Comment: Congratulations to all our new 'diamond geezers' ! :)

Comment: Congrats everyone!